# How to set a value at the first iteration then never change it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a research bar to learn Meteor, JavaScript etc... and the problem is that I want to go to the first Article that matches with the search but say "there is X articles more with your criteria"

I have tried this:

```
'click .tfbutton'(event){
      var research = document.getElementById('tftextinput').value.toLowerCase();
      var nombreValide = 0;
      var lastArticlePos = 0;

      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
          var acutal = obj.textContent.toLowerCase();
            if(acutal.includes(research)){
                nombreValide = nombreValide + 1;
                var position = obj.offsetTop;
                window.scrollTo(0,position);
                document.getElementById('tftextinput').value = "";
            }else{
               document.getElementById('tftextinput').value = "";
              console.log("We can't find an article with your criterias");
            }
        });
        console.log("There is : " + nombreValide + " articles who matchs");
      }, 20)
      },
```

And I want to set `lastArticlePos` at the first iteration then never change it again but still add 1 to `nombreValide`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize it with `null` and set it to something else only if `null`:

```
'click .tfbutton'(event){
      var research = document.getElementById('tftextinput').value.toLowerCase();
      var nombreValide = 0;
      var lastArticlePos = null;

      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
          var acutal = obj.textContent.toLowerCase();
            if(acutal.includes(research)){
                if (lastArticlePos === null) lastArticlePos = i;
                nombreValide = nombreValide + 1;
                var position = obj.offsetTop;
                window.scrollTo(0,position);
                document.getElementById('tftextinput').value = "";
            }else{
               document.getElementById('tftextinput').value = "";
              console.log("We can't find an article with your criterias");
            }
        });
        console.log("There is : " + nombreValide + " articles who matchs");
        console.log("Article position is : " + (lastArticlePos === null) ? "<No article found>" : lastArticlePos);
      }, 20)
      },
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you I should have think about this solution but I didn't ^^' Thank you again !